# How to create a fully transparent Navigation Bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I want to change the Navigation Bar fully transparent like on the picture below.

I tried `<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>` but it is not fully transparent (more like 50%).

Is there a solution? Because i found nothing to it, but I saw some apps that used it like Nova. And its even in googles guidelines https://material.google.com/layout/structure.html#structure-system-bars

[image: Transparent Nav]

Answer (score 7):

I was inspired by Google Keep app, which have similar implementation like shown below:

[image]

So i tried to find a proper post on how to achieve this thing but unfortunately found nothing and also above answers weren't working. So i decided to try out all the flags related to `navigationBar` Android Studio was suggesting.

Let me explain in detail:

1. Only `android:navigationBarColor` won't do any thing when you are using a light theme. But on dark theme, it will work.
2. Setting `windowTranslucentNavigation` to `true` will do 2 things:

   - draw the activity below the soft navbar
   - override `navigationBarColor` and force it to be transparent.

Which will look like below image:

[image]

3. If you use `FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS` (follow @Frankenxtein's answer) you will get below result:

[image]

Which is somehow close to desired result, but it isn't because it draws activity components below navbar. And also it mess your padding and margin (see full screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PMLE.png)). And more, you have to do it for each activity and also have to adjust current margin.

### The Solution

This can be achieved without compromising current layout. To do this in Dark theme, you have no issue, just setting `android:navigationBarColor` will do the work.

However our goal here is to do it with a light theme let (#FFFFFF). Using `android:windowLightNavigationBar` which requires API 27 or higher along with  `android:navigationBarColor` will result what we want.

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
```

Here for my app case `colorPrimaryDark` is #FFFFFF in light theme and dracula in dark theme, you can also declare a new variable for this. Which yields below results:

**Light Theme**
[image]

**Dark Theme**

[image]

Here `android:navigationBarColor` is setting background colour of navbar. And `android:windowLightNavigationBar` setting dark button colours and indicates that background is light as you can understand from it's name.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Great answer - could you expand more on point 3 for `FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS`? I'm trying to achieve a fully transparent navigation bar in a specific case but I can't seem to reproduce it. I'm getting the same results for points 2 and 3.

Comment: 3rd point is simply Frankenxtein's or Marcin Koziński's answer.

Comment: If API version is 27+ the navigation divider don't hide.

Comment: Is there are solution for SDK<27?

Comment: @BryanW you can set    enforceNavigationBarContrast to false in styles.xml but requires minimum api level of 29

Answer (score 4):

Since no one has mentioned this and I spent too much time trying to figure it out on my own. A solution for [API 29+](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge?hl=fr) to make the system bars fully transparent regardless of anything:

```xml
<item name="android:enforceNavigationBarContrast">false</item>
<item name="android:enforceStatusBarContrast">false</item>
```

Comment: This was the solution for me. I was doing everything else but this.

Answer (score 3):

use following code in onCreate of your Activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
Window w = getWindow(); w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            }
```

and in your styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using [`FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS). Documentation explains:

> Flag indicating that this Window is responsible for drawing the
>   background for the system bars. If set, the system bars are drawn with
>   a transparent background and the corresponding areas in this window
>   are filled with the colors specified in `getStatusBarColor()` and
>   `getNavigationBarColor()`.

Set it like that in your Activity's `onCreate`:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for android >= 10
You can try the color by default color android

```xml
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

By the way you can try this

```xml
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```